# How can I create a simple Actionscript 3 project with FDT free

Tags: actionscript, fdt

I've just downloaded FDT free since I want to work on a small actionscript project, according to the website.

> FDT Free is free of charge and the perfect editor for small projects or simply to give FDT a try without any time constraints. This edition is recommended for smaller projects.

But I cannot see any way to create an actionscript project?

The project options I am given are

Air, Web, FDT Plugin and Haxe

Can anyone help me in creating an actionscript project with FDT free?

Thanks

Piers

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a project to run in your browser then create a **Web** project. If you want to run this project on your desktop then create an **Air** project.

For more details on how to configure and set up a project with FDT, please refer to: http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/Basic_AS3_Tutorial#Creating_Your_First_Project